# Is there a way to subtract from spectrogram (stored as a figure) from another in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, spectrogram

I have 2 figures (spectrograms) in MATLAB and I would like to subtract them from one another in order to test their similarity. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: why not save the figures as bitmap image,and then load them to compare ? is　it the precision you are concerning about?

Comment: Yes it is. I think I'm going to look for a different approach.